# concatenate several math expressions in R

Tags: r, expression, paste, plotmath

I know how to get my result if I use one long expression:

```
expression(paste(M[O[2]], " (mg ", O[2], " ", h^-1, " ", kg^-1, ")"))
```

But I tried to break this in chunks, so that the user could select a time and a mass unit (to add flexibility), and then put together the complete expression. Say I just reuse the time and mass units from above but into 3 chunks, which I then try to join again:

```
a = expression(paste(M[O[2]], " (mg ", O[2]))  
b = expression(kg^-1)  
c = expression(h^-1)
```

I have tried

```
text(x, y, expression(a b c))  
text(x, y, paste(a, b, c))  
text(x, y, expression(paste(a, b, c)))
```

but this results in a, b and c remaining characters a, b and c, not the expressions created above. I have tried playing with bquote but I admit to not mastering it and I could not get it to concatenate the 3 plotmath expressions either.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Denis

Comment: I am sorry about the formatting in my post, things that were on separate lines got put onto a single line and I don't see how to edit a post.

Answer (score 4):

Create a list of `a`, `b` and `c` and apply [[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO0Vl.png)]] to each component to get rid of the `expression` part and then substitute the results into `a * b * c * ")"` like this:

```
e <- substitute(a * b * c * ")", lapply(list(a = a, b = b, c = c), "[[", 1))
plot(0, main = e)
```

(continued after plot)

[image: screenshot]

Note that it would be easier if `a`, `b` and `c` were defined using `quote` rather than `expression`.  In that case it simplifies to:

```
a <- quote(paste(M[O[2]], " (mg ", O[2]))  
b <- quote(kg^-1)  
c <- quote(h^-1)  
e <- substitute(a * b * c * ")", list(a = a, b = b, c = c))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. I like the quote version better, of course, I'll read about quote, which I never used before. Thanks a lot, Denis